# Create a sequential set of numbers with a reset for each series in a stacked table

Tags: sql, reset

I am trying to create a column that identifies the order of values and resets with each series in a stacked set of data. For example, I have;

```
Analysis    Loss    
1           9994493    
1           8994493    
2           9994493    
2           8994493    
2           7994493
```

And I want to create a column "Order" so that it populates like this.

```
Analysis    Loss       Order    
1           9994493    1    
1           8994493    2    
2           9994493    1    
2           8994493    2    
2           7994493    3
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: please ignore this question

Comment: @AlexanderAlabaster . . . There is no such thing as "ignore this question".  As the OP, you can delete the if it is no longer appropriate.  However, it has been answered, so you might consider instead accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms support window function, you can try to use `row_number` with window function.

```
SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by Analysis order by Loss desc) Order
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

The `row_number()` window function does just that:

```
SELECT   analysis,
         loss,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY analysis ORDER BY loss DESC) AS "order"
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY 1, 3
```